# Is the monogame content processors required for it to work on different platforms?

Tags: xna, monogame

Can I just use the xna content processor and import all the xnb files, or do I need to use the monogame content project thing and use their processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can use the XNA content processor. That's what most people have been doing while waiting for the MonoGame team to implement their own content processors.

Alternately, you can use raw assets in place of the XNB files. Simply add them to the Content folder of your project and set them to Content / Copy if newer in the properties window. You also need to refer the the file with it's extension in code, e.g.

```
Content.Load<Texture2D>("MyTexture.png");
```

When doing this, I've also found you get better results if you set the blend state to BlendState.NonPremultiplied since the XNB files do this for you.

```
_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, null, null, null, null, viewMatrix * Matrix.CreateScale(screenScale));
```

Comment: but will it be multiplatform?